# how to use scrollfview in a popup window

Tags: android, xml, popupwindow

I am trying to use a scroll view in my pop up window, and it works to an extent, but when I scroll down the text is still visible - how do I use this code in a pop up window?

```
 <ScrollView 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="#333333">
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="10dp"     >
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/popupView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/helpmenu"
        android:textSize="1600pt"  />
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:text="Close"    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: not get "but when I scroll down the text is still visible"?

Comment: Yes so f I scroll down the gray box around it scrolls but the text does not dissapear

Comment: android:textSize="1600pt" is this typo error or intentional ?

Comment: Sorry, yes that was intentional-  I was testing on a tablet and I wanted to see how the scroll view function on phones would work, so I made the text a ridiculous size

Comment: so it is 16pt ..but still not get query if your ScrollView has TextView as it's content so how it will disappear because button 'll take only one row space ? attach the screen-shot.....

Comment: I cant, I do not have a good enough reputation. What happens it looks fine when I open it, but when I scroll the containing box moves down, and leaves the text visible

Comment: Thanks for your help, I decided that I will make the text small, and if someone can't read the instructions, then I will go through this again later if need be. (When I know enough to help people and gain reputation to post pictures)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jcw i found solution to this problem i know its to late, but still for any future use.
Make use of any parent layout like Frame or linear, relative above scroll View and the problem you are facing will be gone.

Comment: Finally!! Thank you, this works perfectly, too late for the app in that I was asking about in the question, but certainly helpful for future apps.

Comment: I tried using Linear as a parent but that didnt work for me.